# org.json cannot be resolved to a module?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-11, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I'm learning Java. To read JSON in my application, I downloaded [this JSON library](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java); which is an automatic module.

I included that library in my module descriptor like:

```java
module art
{
    exports  art.anixt;
    exports  art.coartl;
    exports  art.runeape;
    requires org.json;    // org.json cannot be resolved to a moduleJava(8389908)
}
```

My settings.json in vscode:

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "java.format.settings.url": "Format.xml",
    "java.format.settings.profile": "style",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar" // jar file showing in Referenced library(see screenshot)
    ]
}
```

How do I include the jar file in my module and import it into my Java file?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR*** — As this unresolved [*'Cannot be resolved' errors in projects with module-info.java*](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/881) issue reports, vscode is brain dead when it comes to JPMS and module-info.java.

---

***The  long-winded version***

From my own experience, I can personally vouch for what the reporter of the above-linked vscode issue reports…

> > „*…I've tried both Gradle and Maven…*“
> >
> > …
> >
> > „*…I find that Gradle and Maven will automatically refresh the classpath file and remove my modifications to it, which will bring back the errors…*“
> >
> > …
> >
> > „*…there needs to be module path information set in the classpath file in order for Eclipse to be happy, but there is no good way to do with that from Gradle or Maven…*“

Proof that it's a vscode issue is that the exact same project — *unchanged except for the removal of your comment* — compiles perfectly fine in IntelliJ…

[image: No problems in module-info.java]

Since your project uses neither Maven nor Gradle — *opting instead to use file-based dependency mgt with the jar in the `lib` folder* — you're in even worse shape because you've eliminated the option of applying any JPMS-enabling plugins that could resolve the issue.

For example, by adding the following pom.xml with the appropriate configuration for the *`maven-compiler-plugin`* to my experimental version of your project…

```xml
…
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20200518</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint:unchecked</arg>
                    <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                    <arg>org.json</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
…
```

…Maven does its magic and processes the module-info.java successfully…

[image: No problems in module-info.java]

I've successfully resolved other Stackers' JPMS woes by helping them apply [*that **mrJar** plugin mentioned in that vscode bug report*](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/881#issuecomment-550359767). So if you're open to using Gradle instead of Maven, I could likewise advise you on how to configure that plugin too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did't have experience in xml so can give the path to file xml and do i need to use maven or just pom.xml is enough ?

Comment: And could please provide screenshot of your folder structure ?

Comment: „*…do i need to use maven…*“ – @Srilakshmikanthan — If you haven't already, you will need to [*install Maven*](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). — „*…or just pom.xml is enough…*“ — If you want vscode to process your project as a Maven project, then it must have a pom.xml located in its root directory. The *root* is where the *`Format.xml`* file is in your screenshot. — „*…please provide screenshot…*“  — I already have, actually. You can see the structure of my project in my two screenshots: *`sri .lakshmi.kanthan/src/main/java/art/…`* Then the three sub-packages are located under *`art`*

Comment: Thanks for your responce, I copied the xml but it shows error "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.xml(MarkupNotRecognizedInMisc" Does it full xml or i need to add somthing if i need can you give some reference about that.

Comment: „*…can you give some reference about that…*“– @Srilakshmikanthan — [*Try this*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Maven+tutorial).